# Nacon GC-100 gamepad right stick not working properly on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wine, gamepad

I reciently buyed a Xbox-like PC controller (Nacon GC-100) and I was trying it on Steam and worked pretty good, the problem comes when I use it on non Steam games.

The right Stick works kinda weird, when I try to move it to the right/left the game detects it as I'm moving it up/down and if I move it up/down it doesn't even detect anything.

Searching about this thing I found other people having this problem saying that it was Wine's fault, but in the Wine Control Panel, that has an option to test the controllers you have conected, the right stick was properly detected so I doubt it's related to Wine and now i'm kinda confused on what's the thing that causes the right stick to work like that.

Answer (score 2):

Please test the controller on [game-pad tester](https://gamepad-tester.com/), if it works fine and considering that it works great on Wine's tester then the problem would be with those games you are playing using Wine, which probably don't work seamlessly as they are not native on Ubuntu.

If those games are also available on Steam but not for Ubuntu, go to Steam > Settings > Steam play > Enable Steam Play for supported titles and Enable Steam Play for all other titles.

That should make a lot of unavailable games to be available and will work nicely. You can get further information [here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/linux-gaming-with-ubuntu-desktop-steam-and-proton), I highly recommend reading it before any changes.